# Two-Finger Scrolling on Windows 10 Results in Logout

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling, windows-10-v1703

When I use two-finger scrolling in Windows 10 (any application and any direction), it causes Windows to log out.

After testing a bit, here is what I've managed to find out:

- Scrolling slowly does not cause a log out
- Any scroll action which is more of a "flick" or moving my fingers quickly and holding them on the touchpad causes a log out
- This is deterministic behaviour - it can be reproduced very reliably
- I am on Windows 10 Pro, version **1703**, OS Build **15063.413**

I have **not** restarted after I first discovered this behaviour, in case there is some debugging action I could take, but I'm not sure how I can capture what's going on here.

Is this a known issue? If not, what steps should I take to investigate further?

Comment: KB4034674 (OS Build 15063.540) is last update. update your windows and test again, maybe it is already fixed

Comment: does it happen with the latest update, too?

Comment: No, I was holding off on making any changes because I wanted to find out what was causing it. An upgrade made the behaviour go away, but I don't know how I would have debugged this.

Comment: before trying to "debug" such things for windows10, make sure you use the latest version. MS makes so many changes in a short time that they may already fixed bugs in the last updates

Comment: While technically true, that's not always possible in a short space of time. This particular issue stayed around for a few days while I needed to give a presentation remotely - I make it a point never to update immediately before something like that due to previous unreliability of updates. Generally, I would rather understand my operating system and know the severity of any issue before I blindly update everything.

Comment: do what ever you want I'm out of this discussion because your issue is now fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a restart and upgrade, the issue is no longer reproducible.